# ActiveMQ - how to deal with producer is closed

Tags: activemq-classic, producer

The following code creates a consumer and registers to a queue:

```
PooledConnectionFactory factory = new PooledConnectionFactory(BROKER_URL);
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destQueue = new ActiveMQQueue(queue);
Producer producer = session.createProducer(destQueue);
```

The problem is that we occasionally get 'Producer is closed' exception:

```
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The producer is closed
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.checkClosed(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:196)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.getDestination(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:153)
        at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.<init>(PooledProducer.java:43)
        at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.createProducer(PooledSession.java:361)
```

Restarting the application reestablishes the connection and messages are drained correctly. Is there a way to check if the producer has been closed and refresh the connection?

Comment: Can you share details active mq broker & client libraries version